# Let $G$ be a group and $n\in \Bbb Z$. $\forall x,y\in G$, $x^n=y^n \Rightarrow x=y$ and $xy^n=y^nx$. Thus, prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $n\in \Bbb Z$. $\forall x,y\in G$, $x^n=y^n \Rightarrow x=y$ and $xy^n=y^nx$. Thus, prove that $G$ is abelian. Working backwards, I get $$xy=yx$$$$(xy)^n=(yx)^n$$ but I am unsure on how to show $xy^n=y^nx\Rightarrow (xy)^n=(yx)^n$.

Comment: You haven't said what $n$ is.

Comment: Sorry, n is an integer

Comment: Is $G$ finite? Because in that case there's an easy proof.

Comment: G is a finite group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^{-1}y^n x = (x^{-1} y x)^n.$

Comment: OK, that one is better than the hint I was going to give. You win. My hint was: the map $x\mapsto x^n$ is injective, and $|G|$ is finite.

Comment: @DavidCraven I didn't even see that method! That's also a nice simple argument, although it does require $G$ to be finite which is an unnecessary additional assumption.

Comment: Isn't $x \mapsto x^n$ just an automorphism of $G$, so $xy^n = y^nx$ actually means that $x$ commutes with every $z$ in $G$?

Comment: @Logos That's essentially the argument David is making (I assume you mean $x\mapsto x^n$ not $x^2$). However, this method of proof depends on $G$ being finite. (One should also remark just to avoid potential confusion that $x\mapsto x^n$ is a priori only an automorphism of $G$ as a set, not necessarily as a group.)

Comment: @Stahl, by bad, it was s typo (edited now). Okay, I got the argument then. Instead, if I can see why $x^{-1}y^n x = y^n$, alas I can't understand how to prove that it is also $(x^{-1}yx)^n$. Would you be so kind to give me a hint? Apologies about that: I am rusty with group theory, though I have found the question interesting!

Comment: @Logos Of course: if you want to formally verify this, I suggest using induction. However, I think looking at what happens for small $n$ is pretty convincing in its own right. E.g., for $n = 3,$ we have $$(x^{-1} y x)^3 = x^{-1} y xx^{-1} y xx^{-1} y x = x^{-1} y e y e y x = x^{-1} y^3 x.$$

Comment: @Stahl brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CS24B you're welcome! If this has answered your question, I recommend you accept the answer so that your question is removed from the unanswered list.